# onclick copy value to next available cell in column

Tags: excel, vba, onclick, copy-paste

I have a dropdown list of items which are in a table with corresponding values. Below the dropdown list I have a VLookup to find the value of the item. I need to keep a count of the total value that these are worth. Once the dropdown list is selected I need the value of the VLookup copied and pasted into the next available cell in the column. Complicating this is that each column corresponds to a different person who can have items added to their total in any order.

When column B has an item selected I need to copy the value to the bottom of column B, similarly for column C, etc.

I know I need to do use onclick function but everything I have seen copies onto the next available row without keeping column discipline. Would I need to name each column and onclick function separately or is there a neater solution?

Comment: post some code where is this drop down at the top of each column?